# Understanding how link list works

Tags: java, object

I was given this code to write multiple classes with, but i am having a hard time understand this LinkList. When calling my clear() and my count(E o) method(which are two that is required to write) I am not sure how to run the loop. I am not sure what is referenced has my .length of the array I would call in my class, and keep getting nullpointers. Is size the right variable or should it be something else? Also a bit confused on who to call count(E o) in the main method.

```
public class GenericLinkedList<E> implements List<E> {

private class Node<E>{
    private E data;
    private Node<E> next;
}
private E data;
private Node<E> head = null;
private int size = 0;

private Node<E> nodeAt(int index){
    Node<E> curNode = head;
    int curIndex = 0;
    while(curIndex < index){
        curNode = curNode.next;
        curIndex++;
    }
    return curNode;
}

@Override
public E get(int index) {
    return nodeAt(index).data;
}

@Override
public void add(E value) {
    Node<E> node = new Node<E>();
    node.data = value;

    if(size == 0){
        head = node;
    }else{
        Node<E> curNode = nodeAt(size - 1);
        curNode.next = node;
    }
    size++;
}

public void add(int index, E value){
    Node<E> node = new Node<E>();
    node.data = value;

    if(size == 0){
        head = node;
    }else if(index == 0){
        node.next = head;
        head = node;
    }else{
        Node<E> curNode = nodeAt(index - 1);
        node.next = curNode.next;
        curNode.next = node;
    }
    size++;
}

@Override
public void remove(int index) {
    if(index == 0){
        head = head.next;
    }else{
        Node<E> curNode = nodeAt(index - 1);
        curNode.next = curNode.next.next;
    }

}

@Override
public void set(int index, E value) {
    nodeAt(index).data = value;

}

public String toString(){
    String s = "";
    Node<E> curNode = head;
    s += curNode.data +" -> ";
    while(curNode.next != null){
        curNode = curNode.next;
        s += curNode.data +" -> ";
    }
    s += "null";
    return s;
}

@Override 
public void clear()//Clears out the array object by setting everything to null
{        
    for(int i = 0; i < data.size; i++)
    {    
        remove(0);          
    }
}

@Override
public int count()
{
    int count = 0;
    E temp;
    for(int i = 0;i<size-1;i++)
    {
        if(get(i)!=null)
        {
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
    return count;

}
```

Comment: I was able to figure ouy the clear() function, but i get a nullpointer when i try to call it since everything has been cleared out. It would not let me add anymore values into the array as well so is there a way to keep the array from being collected by the garbage collector?